# Maven unable to resolve org.junit.test

Tags: maven, grails, junit

I am trying to compile and run unit tests in Groovy from the command line. The package structure in the project is not following naming convention - this is something I can`t change at this point. The classes are organized as:

```
src/abc/def/SomeClass.groovy

src/abc/tests/def/TestSomeClass.groovy
```

When I run `mvn test`, the message is:

> unable to resolve class org.junit.Test

and

> unable to resovle class org.junit.Assert

in the class `src/abc/tests/def/TestSomeClass.groovy`.

My POM is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0                       http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <configuration>
               <sources>
                  <source>
                     <directory>src</directory>
                     <includes>
                        <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                     </includes>
                  </source>
               </sources>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>compile</goal>
                     <goal>addSources</goal>
                     <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                     <goal>testCompile</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <includes>
                  <include>**/Test*.groovy</include>
               </includes>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
         <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
         <version>2.4.7</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>4.11</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard Maven directory layout is this:

For production:
`<project>/src/main/groovy/abc/def`

For tests:
`<project>/src/test/groovy/abc/def`

If you arrange your sources according to this scheme, you shouldn't have problems.

[More informations](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki/Examples#additional-sources)

Comment: I refactored the packages/directories, so that they follow the convention 

`src/test/groovy/abc/def/`.

And I`m still getting the same message - unable to resolve org.junit.Test and org.junit.Assert.

If I disable 

`<scope>test</scope>`

the compile is successful ( gmavenplus fires the message for testCompile - compiled xy files ) but no tests are run.